usg audit give erroneous results
I ran the usg audit for cis level1 workstation.  I noted a number of failures and set about to fix some of them.  I then ran the audit again and the failures I fixed show up again.  For example, Disable the GNOME3 Login User List shows failure.  I know I fixed this because when I reboot I do not get the user list, I have to type in a user name and password, yet this still shows as a failure.  It seems to remember all the original failures and repeat them.  Is there some cache somewhere that has to be cleared before I rerun?
